# gerrit set project access add single user was invalid

Tags: gerrit

My gerrit version was v3.0.
I used to add single user in project access in gerrit version v2.15,after i upgrade gerrit version to v3.0, add single user as group was invalid
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the [singleusergroup plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#singleusergroup) v3.0 installed in your Gerrit.

Comment: thx.My Gerrit was build by myself,So it has no singleuser plugin by default.Install it after I install v3.0.6 make it ok